# Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to perform a migration in Ruby on Rails 4, and I am running into the following error:

```
********-C02MGBVJFD57:myapp michaelsutyak$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 22):

First verify that you have indeed run `mysql.server start`, as `tmp/mysql.sock` is generated on startup (as is tradition).  If you are still encountering difficulties, run `mysqladmin variables | grep socket` and update the information in your `database.yml` accordingly

Comment: ah the ol' "make sure the server is running" trick, eh? worked like a charm!

Comment: To find the socket path that is actually in use you may need to do it like this:
mysqladmin -u root variables | grep socket